# IP aliasing on en0 on macbook

Tags: macos, ip

I am trying to add multiple IP addresses to my en0 interface on my macbook with macOS sierra 10.13.3 version, but it is not working as expected.

sudo ifconfig en0 alias 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.255

sudo ifconfig en0 alias 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.255

sudo ifconfig en0 alias 10.0.0.3 255.255.255.255

After doing this, 10.0.0.1 resolves. I can ping.

But not 10.0.0.2 & 10.0.0.3.

Is this a known limitation or bug? 
Any additional steps need to be done to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a restriction?

I am able to circumvent this problem by using loopback interface.

sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.2 0xff000000 
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.3 0xff000000

and this enabled me to successfully setup port forwarding on same port across IPs on my machine.

But would be nice to know why it didn't work on en0.